# Don't use the new transparency of Yosemite

Tags: cocoa

Is there any way to remove the Mac OS Yosemite transparency in my Cocoa app? Didn't found any setting at `NSWindow` or `NSToolbar` for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSWindow` adopts `NSAppearanceCustomization`, which means it has an `appearance` property. I believe that setting that to `[NSAppearance appearanceNamed:NSAppearanceNameAqua]` will turn off vibrancy for the window.